# webdriver is not copying in the root project C#

Tags: nuget

I had made a custom nuget package which is referencing `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`. When I build this project, I could see the `chromedriver.dll` copied to bin/debug folder.

This is how my .csproj file looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageId>UIFramework</PackageId>
        <RootNamespace>UIFramework</RootNamespace>
        <Version>1.0.6</Version>
        <PackageVersion>1.0.6</PackageVersion>
        <Language>C#</Language>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Protractor" Version="0.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.8.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" Version="17.17134.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="90.0.4430.2400" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" Version="0.27.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" Version="17.17134.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools" Version="3.141.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="App.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now I am trying to reference my custom package in a new dotnet project. But When I am building this project, I could not see the `chromedriver.dll` copied in my new project